# to write a program to find all the pair of 5digit number such that their sum is also a 5digit number

Tags: python, list

its my school assignment to write a program to find all the possible pair of 5digit number such that their sum I s also a 5digit number (e.g.- (13526,66471),(53972+25016),etc). I want to use basic in built functions like for and while loops and if,else statements , lists,etc.

```
temp=[]
x=0
y=0
while x<10:
    n1=[x,x,x,x,x]
    x+=1
    while y<10:
        n2=[y,y,y,y,y]
        y+=1
    for i in range(0,5):
        for j in range(0,5):
            if n1[i]+n2[j]<=0:
                temp.append((n1[i],n2[j]))
        
                    
print(temp)
print(len(temp))
```

I tried this code but as expected it didn't wrk.

Comment: Why don't you use integers and count from 10000 to 99999 instead of using lists? Is it a requirement?

Comment: Yeah i also thought about about that at first but it's a condition to solve using lists, loops and conditional statements

Comment: You should post the exact assignment. I don't think using "lists, loops, and conditionals" exclude integers and mathematical operations (which you seem to be using in your failed attempt anyway).

Comment: You can do this without programming.  For 10000, there are 79999 possible numbers.  For 10001, there are 79997 possible, For 10002, there are 79995 possible.  This continues until 49999, which has one possible (50000).  So, the answer is the sum of all odd numbers below 80,000, which is 1,600,000,000.

Comment: yeah and it can also be done with the permutation and combination methods but its a assignment for our python class

Answer (score -1):

It should work I guess

```
l=[]
n=10000
while n<100000:
    for i in range(10000,100000):
        s=n+i
        if len(str(s))==5:
            l.append(s)
        else:
            pass
    n=n+1

print(len(l))
```

Comment: The OP's comment states that they are not allowed to use this method.

Comment: oh sorry my bad

Comment: Actually we are doing the chapter on lists so it's necessary to solve the problem using list.